# Updating Cache Not Working

Tags: software-center

I'm trying to install software, but the Software Center (after adding the Multiverse option) sits stuck on `Querying Software Sources`. It never goes any further and consequently won't let me install anything. I'm not offline - internet connection works fine.

Does this just take a very long time or is it actually stuck? It's been more than 10 mins and that bar hasn't changed. I'm on a 10mbps line.

Comment: close the software center and update the repositories through terminal by running `sudo apt-get update` command.

Comment: and If you are getting any error please paste here. we will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

uninstall software center

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now install software center:-

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found by simply browsing instead of searching for apps I could get the software to install. Search wants a repository, but browsing appears to know where to find it.